# Как сделать несколько счётчиков кликов?

Tags: javascript

Через php клики по кнопке сохраняются в текстовый документ.

Если одна кнопка на странице, то всё работает.

```
<a href="#" class="count">кнопка</a>
```

Как можно сделать много счётчиков на странице?
Допустим добавлю я разные классы, а как в js их выполнять?

```
<a href="#" class="count_1">кнопка1</a>
<a href="#" class="count_2">кнопка2</a>
...
```

Не копировать же js 5000 раз и менять только `count`.

```
$(function(){
function get_counter(a,b){
    $.get('click_counter/index.php',{type:b,href:a.attr('href')},function(d){
        a.find('.click_counter').html(d);
    });
}
var click_trigger = ".count";
$(click_trigger).each(function(){
    $(this).append(" <span class='click_counter'></span>");
    get_counter($(this),'');
});
$('body').on("click",click_trigger,function(){
    get_counter($(this),'set');
});
})
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что вашим кнопкам нужны разные классы? Может навешивать один и тот же класс, но разные id? Решение конечно есть, но похоже на XY-проблему

Comment: Можно и разные `id` прописать, как в js это сделать?

Comment: можно через `data` например вот так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/806286/232932 да, определились бы вы, JavaScript вам нужен или JQuery, если второй, то для него есть специальный тег

Comment: Я там ничего не понял, как к моему js это применить? В ссылку поставлю `data-id="001" и тд`

Answer (score 1):

## как в JavaScript выбрать (найти) элементы по классу с использованием css selector ?

```js
window.addEventListener('load',() => {
  let _NodeList = document.body.querySelectorAll('[class^=count]');
  console.log(_NodeList.length)
})
```

```html
<a href="#" class="count">кнопка1</a>
<a href="#" class="count_1">кнопка1</a>
<a href="#" class="count_2">кнопка2</a>
```

### список ссылок на документацию:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
https://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom

Comment: тк автор использует jquery, добавлю, что аналогично и там - `var click_trigger = "[class^=count]";`

Comment: Почему выводит `Undefinded href`

Comment: Он всё равно считает все счетчики как один

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так раздать ссылкам айдишники если нужно как-то идентифицировать, а работать с одним классом.

```js
var count_btns = document.body.querySelectorAll('.count');

for (var i = 0; i < count_btns.length; i++) {
  count_btns[i].id = 'a' + i;
  count_btns[i].appendChild(document.createElement('span'));
  count_btns[i].onclick = handler;
}

function handler(event) {
  var span = event.target.querySelector('span');
  if (!span) span = event.target;
  var count = parseInt(span.innerText);
  span.innerText = Number.isNaN(count) ? 1 : ++count;
};
```

```html
<a href="#" class="count">кнопка1 </a>
<a href="#" class="count">кнопка2 </a>
<a href="#" class="count">кнопка3 </a>
```

Comment: через `data-id` лучше бы. `let id = event.srcElement.dataset.id`

Comment: @qwabra ну это уже тонкости реализации, если гарантируется уникальность на странице, то все и так ок

Comment: У меня уже есть в ссылке `id` и `data-id` их менять нельзя, а только использовать можно.

Comment: @steep  ну заведите любой кастомный атрибут