# Javascript Увеличить высоту элемента от динамически изменяемого значения

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!
Вопрос такой: есть простая таблица, в которой некие коэффициенты, значение которых варьируется от 0,1 до 1,0. Под таблицей есть несколько блоков, которые должны изменять свою высоту пропорционально коэффициенту в таблице.
Например: блок с высотой 100px. Коэффициент в таблице изменился с 1,0 на 0,5 - блок уменьшил свою высоту на 50%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', load)

function load() {
  /**
   * массив с коэффициентами
   * @type {NodeListOf<HTMLInputElement>}
   */
  let coList = document.body.getElementsByClassName('co')

  /**
   * массив с контейнерами
   * @type {NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement>}
   */
  let blockList = document.body.getElementsByClassName('block')

  // --
  cycle(coList, blockList)
}

/**
 * обойти оба массива и связать
 * @param {NodeListOf<HTMLInputElement>} _coList
 * @param {NodeListOf<HTMLDivElement>} _blockList
 */
function cycle(_coList, _blockList) {
  for (let _co of _coList) {
    let coDatasetId = _co.dataset.id
    qwa: //найти и добавить EventListener
      for (let _block of _blockList) {
        if (coDatasetId == _block.dataset.id) {
          add(_co, _block)
          break qwa
        }
      }
  }
}

/**
 * функция, которая добавляет `addEventListener` на собитые `change` элемента `HTMLInputElement`
 * @param {HTMLInputElement} _co
 * @param {HTMLDivElement} _block
 */
function add(_co, _block) {
  //#region вычисление стиля в том числе из css
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(_block)
  let height = style.getPropertyValue('height')
  //#endregion вычисление стиля в том числе из css
  _co.addEventListener('change', foo)
  /**
   * @param {Event} _e
   */
  function foo(_e) {
    let h = parseInt(height) * _co.value
    _block.style.height = h + 'px'
  }

}
```

```css
.block {
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="co" data-id="1" type="range" min="0.1" max="1" step="0.1" value="1"></td>
    <td><input class="co" data-id="2" type="number" min="0.1" max="1" step="0.1" value="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="block" data-id="1">контейнер один</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="block" data-id="2">контейнер два</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Простите за наглость, но никак не могу понять, как захватить данные из ячейки таблицы.

Comment: `td class="co"` и заменить `_co.value` на `parseInt(_co.innerHTML)`

Comment: точнее `td class="co" data-id="1"`

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял как в таблице изменяются значения, но приведу пример с обычными кнопками.

```js
document.getElementById("buttons").addEventListener('click', e => {
  if(e.target.tagName != "BUTTON") return false // если событие вызвано не кнопкой
  var factor = +e.target.getAttribute("data-factor") // достаем коэффициент 
  var el = document.getElementById('field') // ссылка на объект для изменения
  var height = el.getAttribute("data-height") // достаем изначальную высоту
  el.style.height = `${height * factor}px` // пересчитываем новую высоту
})
```

```css
#field {
  transition: height .3s ease-in-out;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: pink
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button class="btn" data-factor="0.1">0,1</button>
  <button class="btn" data-factor="0.5">0,5</button>
  <button class="btn" data-factor="1">1</button>
</div>
<div id="field" data-height="200"></div>
```

Comment: Значения в таблице будут меняются скриптом. Задача в том, чтобы другим скриптом считывать информацию из ячеек таблицы, и менять высоту блоков. Блоки имеют высоту в %.